# How to manually select target device in Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio 2.2, how do I switch the device I am running my application on?

Before the update (to 2.2) a pop window will ask me which device I want to run my application on every time I hit run. Now it automatically runs it on the same device without asking.

On Run > Edit Configurations > app > Deployment Target Options, I have "Use same device for future launches" unchecked.

Currently I am unplugging the last run device in order for the device select pop-up to show.

[image: This is what the run config looks like]

Comment: It sounds like you have the right options set. Leaving "Use same device for future launches" unchecked should allow you to select which device to run on each time.

Comment: Yeah it used to until I updated to 2.2. Not sure what the new InstantRun is but maybe it has to do with how it is configured. Edit: Yes it is instant run. I disabled it an now back to normal. Thank for commenting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

You have to stop your app before, next you can run the app again now android studio will ask you again.

Answer (score 4):

Press the little [app] button (between the hammer and the play button in the toolbar) -> Edit configurations... -> In the "General" tab, in the "Deployment target Options" uncheck "Use same device for future launches".

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable Instant Run. Now the target device select show up every time I run the app. To disable Instant Run go to File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Instant Run, uncheck "Enable Instant Run ...."

Edit: A better answer is provided by David Gonzalez.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks.